# Principles Governing Shiny Code to Shiny Module Conversion (Not included in RStudio Article)

Tags: r, module, shiny

I recently updated R and shiny.

The problem I am having is translating Shiny code into shiny modules. I thought the RStudio guide was very good, but I seem to be missing something fundamental. I would love any direct guidance on the project I am working on. I would also love recommended principles for how to convert from Shiny code to modularized code, particularly hints missing from the RStudio article

---

My goal in the shiny app below (which is part of a larger project) is to create an app that allows someone to load a .csv file, transform that file into a dissimilarity matrix, and download the matrix.

I have code that works in Shiny, but I haven't been able to convert it into a modularized version.

**Note**: Because I couldn't figure out how to add a separate .csv file for people to use when evaluating this code, and I wanted to make sure I included sample code,  I tossed in sample data and commented out the code that would have allowed people to select an external .csv file. I hope that doesn't mess things up too much.

```
library(dplyr)
library(cluster)
library(shiny)

bin <- sample(letters[1:10], 50, replace = TRUE) %>% as.factor()
df <- matrix(bin, ncol = 5) %>% as.data.frame()

# User Input Function
cardsortInput <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fileInput(
      inputId = "datafile",
      label = "Card Sort Results (.csv)",
      accept = c(
        "text/csv",
        "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
        ".csv")
    ),
    checkboxInput(inputId = "header",
                  label = "Header",
                  value = TRUE),
    checkboxInput(inputId = "strings",
                  label = "Strings as Factors",
                  value = TRUE),
    selectInput(inputId = "dmetric",
                label = "Distance Metric",
                choices = c("Euclidean" = "euclidean",
                            "Manhattan" = "manhattan",
                            "Gower" = "gower"),
                selected = "gower"),
    checkboxInput(inputId = "standard",
                  label = "Data Standardization",
                  value = FALSE),
    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Dissimilarity Matrix'),
    br(),
    br(),
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "Card Sort Data",
         tableOutput(
         outputId = "cs_table")
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Dissimilarity Matrix",
        tableOutput(
          outputId = "cs_dissMatrix")
      )
    )
  )
}

# Server Function
cardsort <- function(input, output, session) {
  userFile <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$datafile, message = FALSE))
    input$datafile
  })

  #dataframe <- reactive({
   # read.csv(
    #  file = userFile()$data.path,
     # header = input$header,
      #stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  #})

  dataframe <- reactive({df
  })

  diss_matrix <- reactive({
    data <- dataframe()
    if (is.null(data))
      return(NULL)
    daisy(
      x = data,
      metric = input$dmetric,
      stand = input$standard) %>%
      as.matrix()
  })
  output$dissMatrix <- renderTable({
    diss_matrix()
  })
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {paste("data-",
                                 Sys.Date(),
                                 ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(diss_matrix(),
                file,
                row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}

#########

ui <- fluidPage(
  cardsortInput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  datafile <- callModule(cardsort, "test")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Questions for "general guidance" are too broad and likely to be closed. Please include a specific programming question in your post. What exactly is the problem you are facing? Describe specific errors you are getting or the desired behavior that you are unable to achieve.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what do you want to convert into modules... but when assigning input ids inside a module you should use the `ns` function created (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html). Without `ns` you'd assign the same ids every time you called the module.

Comment: Mr. Flick, Thanks for the comment. Two thoughts. (1) The specific problem I am having is that I am able to generate the UI and Server functions for loadings the .csv file. However, nothing seems to be happening with respect to the transformation into a dissimilarity matrix. (2) I agree about asking for general guidance; my bad. My hope was that someone could share the steps they go through in modularizing shiny code. I think that would be valuable to someone learning the process. I've had difficulty finding examples I could try and mimic.

Comment: user5029763, *head desk multiple times* Thanks. I'll check that. I went through about three days worth of iterations trying to figure this out. At some point I completely forgot about them and never remembered. THANKS.

Comment: I thought including the namespace function would solve the problem, but it didn't. With regards to what I wanted to convert into modules, if you look at the very bottom there is what I hoped to be the modularized version. My goal was to shrink the content above to the modularized code below and reuse it elsewhere. 
    ui <- fluidPage(
      cardsortInput("test")
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      datafile <- callModule(cardsort, "test")
    }

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Comment: Supplement: I get ERROR: unused argument (inputId = "header")

Comment: It seems you have misspelled some variables too, eg `output$dissMatrix` should be `output$cs_dissMatrix`